# Error Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(quartet, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=1m"

Tags: r, ggplot2

> Error  -Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(quartet, aes(x,y)) +
> geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=1m"

Command enetered :

```
ggplot(quartet, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method=1m,se=FALSE) + 
    facet_wrap(~set)
```

How to fix this error , anyone ?

> Error  -Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(quartet, aes(x,y)) +
> geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=1m"

Command enetered :

```
    ggplot(quartet, aes(x,y)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_smooth(method=1m,se=FALSE) + 
       facet_wrap(~set)
```

How to fix this error , anyone ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get assistance, we are going to need more from you than just the error. What were you trying to do? Show us your code and give us enough example data to run it. See this question for how to make a good reproducible example for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: It looked like you have metbod `1m`  instead of `lm`  ... and it should be in quotation marks.  `geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) `